# how to make multiple keywords in sparql?

Tags: php, rdf, sparql

I make a search system that has two categories and a keyword. 
How to make two keywords for more specific results using SPARQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can just add more keywords in your RDF data (and SPARQL query), the cardinality is unrestricted.